# Why can I set the text in a textbox but I can't clear it?

Tags: javascript

I have this written in a certain Javascript function.

```
document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML = "some text";
```

This does what you'd expect. However, if I slightly modify it to try to clear the text box like this

```
document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML = "";
```

It doesn't work. Why?

Comment: To clarify, this is a textarea you are talking about rather than `<input type='text'>`?

Comment: This generally works. Can you create a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: This typically works as you have it. See an example http://jsfiddle.net/RvZDV/

Comment: What browser are you seeing this on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why `innerHTML` is working in that particular case but the more appropriate property to use is `value`

```
document.getElementById('textbox').value = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
document.getElementById("textbox").value= "";
```